# Android : about performance

Tags: android, performance, optimization

I'm making an android game that start to get a little bit too needy in term of CPU, so I was asking myself what can I change to make it a little bit easier for the phone allocate memory.

So my question is: Is assignation less needy than instantation?

Let's say I have a `onDraw` method that gets called to draw sprites and stuff on my view. Everytime it's called I do a `rect1 = new Rect(...)` inside this method. Would it be better in general (and for this specific example) to declare the `rect1` in my class constructor and do `rect1.bottom = ...; rect1.top = ...;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule in Java game programming (Android or otherwise) is to avoid `new` in your game loop as much as possible. Reuse whatever you can. Not only is creating new, temporary objects time consuming, but it will also trigger the garbage collector more often, wasting even more cycles.

Comment: And in fact Android used to have lints about any call to new in onDraw.  I think it still does.

Answer (score 0):

Memory allocation will be always more costly than assigning a value in OnDraw.